# React to Spinner totally populated

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am creating a Spinner, I am populating it from data from a database, and I would like to react in case it receives only one result, and call a method automatically only in that case.

I have a log, after setting the adapter, and it always says 0 result, despite the fact I have more results, when I m running the app.

I have searched custom adapters, but I haven't seen anything that helps me. I haven't seen anything in array adapter class, which is what I am using.

Anybody knows how to do it?

Thank you.

--EDIT--

My code (by request):

```
spinner.setAdapter(DB.GetAdapter(getActivity()));
Log.i("TAG", "Number: "+spinner.getAdapter().getCount());

    if(spinner.getAdapter().getCount()==1){


        spinner.setSelection(1);
        String name=spinner.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();
        methodINeedToCall();
    }
```

In DB class, getAdapter() method:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        DDBB db = new DDBB(context);
        db.open();

        Cursor c = db.getData();
        String tempNombre;
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            tempNombre = c.getString(3);
            adapter.add(tempNombre);
        }
        db.close();
        return adapter;
```

Comment: you have to show the code

Comment: I don't know how it would be of help (it is a regular spinner) but there you go...

Comment: Am I right that this log is showing `0`? `Log.i("TAG", "Number: "+spinner.getAdapter().getCount());`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But later the Spinner has things. I need to react when the item is completed.

Comment: then `if(spinner.getAdapter().getCount()==1){` is a correct code for this. What is a problem with it?

Comment: it always says 0, but later I have results. That code is executed before the Spinner has been replenished with the results from DB.

Comment: what makes a problem to copy it to place where you update adapted?

Comment: It is already placed where adapter is updated. The problem is, the Activity is presented to user BEFORE the Spinner is ready. So, when that code is executed, it is always 0. I need some kind of listener that fires a method when Spinner has finished, but I am unable to find something like that.